# React .useEffect

Tags: reactjs, useeffect

При старте приложения,useEffect срабатывает ,в тот момент когда происходит инициализация State.

```
const [token, tokenSort] = useState(false);
```

Так как useEffect связан по token. В дальнейшем если изменяется token, useEffect отрабатывает. Вопрос можно ли каким то образом отменить первое срабатывание, при инициализации useState?

```
  useEffect(() => {

 }, [token]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам useEffect такого не предусматривает, но можно ref использовать, например

```
const someFunction = () => {
    
    const changeCounter = useRef(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
    
        if(changeCounter.current){
        
            // ...Ваш обработчик
        
        }

        changeCounter.current = true;
    
    }, [token]);
    
}
```

Comment: У меня тоже возникла только такая идея, только в if я проверял, не значения useRef а тот же useState. Если useState изначально false. В условии if (!false). Спасибо за ответ. А то самопридуманые костыли это хорошо)) а вдруг кто то знает какие то, кастомные штуки, о которых я не в курсе.